# PLS-00201: identifier 'NO_EMPLOYEES' must be declared

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Hi Please i need assistance as im stuggling with the following error: 
PLS-00201: identifier 'NO_EMPLOYEES' must be declared

```
CREATE or replace PACKAGE police_employee_mgmt AS 
   no_employees NUMBER;
   FUNCTION insert_employee
   (emp_id NUMBER, emp_name VARCHAR2, emp_grade NUMBER, emp_password VARCHAR2, emp_username VARCHAR2)
RETURN NUMBER;
   PROCEDURE delete_employee(emp_id NUMBER);
   PROCEDURE change_employee_grade(emp_id NUMBER, emp_grade NUMBER);
END police_employee_mgmt;
```

then a function is created to give the variable a value:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION number_of_employees
RETURN NUMBER IS
total_employees NUMBER;
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) 
    INTO total_employees 
    FROM pl_police_employee;
    RETURN(total_employees);
END;
```

Then...

```
BEGIN
no_employees := number_of_employees();
END;
```

Comment: Out of interest, do you have a package body at all, and if so should the standalone function and the anonymous block be part of that body?

Comment: Your error message should contain a line number.

Answer (score 2):

As the error states, you need to declare no_employees. I asume your last code block is outside the package where you did declare it. I think you can use anonymous declares as well:

```
DECLARE
  num_employees NUMBER;
BEGIN
  num_employees := number_of_employees();
  ...
END
```

Comment: BTW: i use a different variable name for two reasons, first of all `no_` is a pretty confusing prefix and secondly having different names for different things helps to identify the location of the error more quickly.